# How to use ExceuteSQL from AWS SDK for Oracle RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

```
POST /ExecuteSql HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
   "awsSecretStoreArn": "string",
   "database": "string",
   "dbClusterOrInstanceArn": "string",
   "schema": "string",
   "sqlStatements": "string"
}
```

The problem is with the dbClusterOrInstanceArn field which is giving error when I am giving the RDS instance ARN.

```
"errorType": "BadRequestException",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid cluster arn:
```

Is there any other way to execute query on Oracle RDS through Lambda

The documentation says:

```
dbClusterOrInstanceArn
The ARN of the Aurora Serverless DB cluster.

Type: String

Length Constraints: Minimum length of 11. Maximum length of 100.

Required: Yes
```

Does this mean that it will only work for AUrora ?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rdsdataservice/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteSql.html